# Why will a connector add some inductance if it is soldered or not?

Tags: connector, inductance

According to this [AN](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN90030.pdf) :

[image]

I do not understand how the inductance can reduce if the connector is soldered or not. I mean the length of the "traces" will not change.  I agree that the resistance will change as there is a contact which is not as good as if it was soldered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they really meant to say is: "use of **mated** connectors **is** not recommended".

That is: connect directly through short lines (e.g.: soldered wires or PCB traces). Don't run a long line, such as through a pair of connectors, because doing so will introduce additional inductance and slow down the drive. The point is short lengths, not whether or not it goes through solder.

Comment: That was clearly not clear  from Nexperia to me

Answer (score 2):

It tends to be the case that general purpose high-current connector systems have larger loop areas and resulting inductances. If a driver module is connected like this to the FET it will tend to have degraded gate drive performance.

There *are* connector systems with differential pairs and very tightly controlled impedance, but the current limits on these systems are often less that the drive currents in question.

Bottom line, connector systems can be used, but selection of the right system requires significant care.